# AWS.SDK TransferUtility.Upload hangs

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net, awss3transferutility

I have the following code

```
Dim fileTransferUtility = New TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(credentials,region))
Dim fileTransferUtilityRequest = New TransferUtilityUploadRequest With {
   .BucketName = bucketName,
   .FilePath = sourceFileName,
   .PartSize = 6291456,
   .Key = awsFileKey
}
fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest)
```

This code worked just fine up until

- AWSSDK.Core version="3.3.107.5"
- AWSSDK.S3 version="3.3.111.6"

But hangs starting from

- AWSSDK.Core version="3.3.107.6"
- AWSSDK.S3 version="3.3.111.6"

It does never return, with exception or anything. It simply hangs.

The environment is

- OS Info: Windows 10 Pro, Windows Server 2012 +
- Build Environment Visual Studio 2019, 16.6.2
- Targeted .NET Platform: 4.7.1

Did anyone encountered this problem, and found any solution?

---

I created an issue on AWS.SDK at
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed with versions
AWSSDK.Core 3.3.107.16
AWSSDK.S3 3.3.111.17